# MPI Parallel File writing in HDF5 format from1D contiguous struct to 3D

Tags: parallel-processing, hdf5, mpich

I am trying to write a set of variables (gridinfo object of dep_var class) in parallel using a compound datatype. My total system size is NX x NY x NZ and worker info is stored in worker(obj of worker_info class). The function "write_hdf(...)" is being excecuted by only the workers.

Now, my gridinfo is a 1D array of objects in the form (i+offset_x) Ny*Nz+(k+offset_z)*Ny+(j+offset_y) . I have paddings at ends which are specifies by offset_x,offset_y and offset_z. I am unable to understand how to specify this offset for 1D array in memspace when I want my dataspace to be a 3D array. Note that the main_offset_x,y,z are the offsets for the worker block on dataspace.

Using the hdf tutorials I was able to write up to this. I would appreciate if you could provide me some tips as to how to move forward. Thanks in advance!!

```
void write_hdf(MPI_Comm comm,MPI_Func *mpi_obj,int iter){
    stringstream hdf_fname;
    hdf_fname<<"Out_"<<iter<<".h5";
    string hdf_filename = hdf_fname.str();
    //Create a new file collectively and release property list identifier.
    hid_t fapl_id=H5Pcreate(H5P_FILE_ACCESS);
    H5Pset_fapl_mpio(fapl_id,comm,MPI_INFO_NULL);
    hid_t file_id=H5Fcreate(hdf_filename.c_str(),H5F_ACC_TRUNC,H5P_DEFAULT,fapl_id);
    H5Pclose(fapl_id);

    int RANK=3;
    hsize_t dims[RANK];
    herr_t status;
    dims[0]=NX;dims[1]=NY;dims[2]=NZ;
    //Create dataspace
    hid_t dataspace_id=H5Screate_simple(RANK,dims,NULL);

    //Create compound datatype
    hid_t cmpd_dtype_id=H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND,sizeof(dep_var));        
    status=H5Tinsert(cmpd_dtype_id, "Temperature", HOFFSET(dep_var,Temp),H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status=H5Tinsert(cmpd_dtype_id, "fs", HOFFSET(dep_var,fs),H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT);
    status = H5Tset_order(cmpd_dtype_id, H5T_ORDER_LE);

    //Create chunk dataset
    dims[0]=worker->Nx;dims[1]=worker->Ny;dims[2]=worker->Nz;
    hid_t plist_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_CREATE);
    H5Pset_chunk(plist_id, RANK, dims);
    hid_t dataset_id=H5Dcreate(file_id,"All_VAR",cmpd_dtype_id,dataspace_id,H5P_DEFAULT,plist_id,H5P_DEFAULT);
    H5Pclose(plist_id);
    H5Sclose(dataspace_id);

    //create memspace for each worker
    hsize_t offset[RANK],block[RANK],stride[RANK],count[RANK];
    hid_t memspace_id=H5Screate_simple(RANK,dims,NULL);
    count[0] =worker->Nx;count[1] = worker->Ny ;count[2]=worker->Nz;
    stride[0] = 1;stride[1] = 1;stride[2]=1;
    block[0] = dims[0];block[1] = dims[1];block[2]=dims[2];
    offset[0]=worker->main_offset_x;
    offset[1]=worker->main_offset_y;
    offset[2]=worker->main_offset_z;

    dataspace_id = H5Dget_space(dataset_id);
    status = H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataspace_id, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, stride, count, block);

    //Create property list for collective dataset write.
    hid_t xf_id=H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_XFER);
    H5Pset_dxpl_mpio(xf_id,H5FD_MPIO_COLLECTIVE);

    //Write File
    status = H5Dwrite(dataset_id, cmpd_dtype_id, memspace_id, dataspace_id,xf_id, &(gridinfo[0]));

    //Free
    H5Sclose(dataspace_id);
    H5Sclose(memspace_id);
    H5Dclose(dataset_id);
    H5Pclose(xf_id);
    H5Fclose(file_id);
}

class dep_var{
    public:
        double Temp;
        double fs;
};

class worker_info{
    public:
        int Nx,Ny,Nz;//Worker size
        int real_Nx,real_Ny,real_Nz;//Size with padding
        int offset_x,offset_y,offset_z; //Offsets for padding
        int main_offset_x,main_offset_y,main_offset_z; //offsets for this worker on dataspace
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DuFM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
It is all about indexing, we can regard 3D array as a "book" which has NZ pages with each page NX(column)*NY(row) words.  We now numbering words in this "book” row by row. 
Then the index of a word may be written as:
  index=NX*NY*z+y*NX+x;
```

Regards.